# aspx url to mvc controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an aspx page Test.aspx. It handles requests like
Test.aspx?First=value1&Second=value2&third=value3
How can I use routing to redirect this url to
TestController/MyAction?First=value1&Second=value2&third=value3

I know I can create an aspx and perform redirect in it`s page load. But seems ugly and I think it can be done with some custom route.

What I`ve tried was: [this solution](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/108/Handling-Legacy-URLs-with-ASP.NET-MVC)

but it didnt work for me.

I remember, that Test.aspx should not be on a disk. I don`t have it, and routing is still not working. Have no idea on what can cause this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding a route like the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Test",
    "Test.aspx",
    new { controller = "TestController", action = "Show" }
);
```

Just remember that the route will not work if the `Test.aspx` file is still on disk.

Also, ideally you would want to have a permanent redirect so the search engine links etc get updated to point to your new urls.

Comment: Unit test throws exception like
MvcContrib.TestHelper.AssertionException: Expected Test/Show but was Test.aspx.

Comment: actually i thing routing can work for existing files... have you looked at this documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.routeexistingfiles.aspx

Comment: Link is not working for me, can you, please, post what`s there in a separated post?

Comment: Didn't work for me right away but once I moved it to the top of the routes (they're evaluated in order of declaration) it worked.  Cheers!